# Function returns differently when called from sub vs excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, error-handling

I have a simple function here that performs a calculation on a range of values. The range will always have 5 values. The range should also be one dimensional.
In an attempt to cover an out of range case, I have tried to add error handling that will prompt the user of the functions limitation.

When I test a range with an x value > 1 from a subroutine, I only get the error msg once as intended. However, when I attempt the same range of cells from a worksheet, I get the error msg *many* times.

I don't understand why I would get different results from a worksheet vs. a subroutine.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
Public Function RIAJ_SCORE_RANGE(Range_FROM_million_TO_gold As Range) As Double

On Error GoTo eh

Dim millionTOgold As Variant

millionTOgold = Range_FROM_million_TO_gold.Value

Dim i As Long
Dim x As Integer

x = 1

If x <> 1 Then GoTo er1

For i = LBound(millionTOgold) To UBound(millionTOgold)
If i = 1 Then
RIAJ_SCORE_RANGE = millionTOgold(i, 1) * 10
ElseIf i = 2 Then RIAJ_SCORE_RANGE = RIAJ_SCORE_RANGE + millionTOgold(i, x) * 7.5
ElseIf i = 3 Then RIAJ_SCORE_RANGE = RIAJ_SCORE_RANGE + millionTOgold(i, x) * 5
ElseIf i = 4 Then RIAJ_SCORE_RANGE = RIAJ_SCORE_RANGE + millionTOgold(i, x) * 2.5
ElseIf i = 5 Then RIAJ_SCORE_RANGE = RIAJ_SCORE_RANGE + millionTOgold(i, x)
Else: GoTo eh

End If
Next i

er1:
    x = 1
    MsgBox ("Function requires range from a single column")
    GoTo eh
    
eh:
    Exit Function

End Function
```

This sub runs as intended, returning error msg and exiting the function. From Excel, passing the same range prompts the error msg 32 times.

```
Sub testRange()

RIAJ_SCORE_RANGE (ActiveSheet.Range("E86:F91"))

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> RIAJ_SCORE_RANGE (ActiveSheet.Range("E86:F91"))
> ```

Drop the parentheses, they're let-coercing your `Range` into a value through an implicit *default member* call (`Range.[_Default]`, a hidden member that "branches" to other members depending on how it's parameterized) that ultimately attempts to pass a 2D `Variant` array (i.e. exactly what you would be getting with `ActiveSheet.Range("E86:F91").Value`) to a procedure that wants to work with a `Range` object, hence the *type mismatch* error.

This would be passing the `Range` object without let-coercing it into an array:

```
RIAJ_SCORE_RANGE ActiveSheet.Range("E86:F91")
```

That said, invoking a function without capturing its return value is (*should be*) useless, because a function (especially one intended to run from a worksheet cell) should not have any side-effects: it takes inputs, computes a result based on these inputs, and outputs a result. Looks like that's exactly what you have here, so.. good job!

You *do* need the parentheses when you are capturing a function's return value:

```
MsgBox RIAJ_SCORE_RANGE(ActiveSheet.Range("E86:F91"))
```

Notice the missing space between the function name and the `(` character: that's the VBE telling you that the `(...)` parentheses are delimiting an *argument list*. When there's a space (the VBE will *force* that space, you can't fight it), the parentheses are let-coercing the *first* argument in the argument list - `MsgBox` is also a function, and we're not capturing its return value here, so no parentheses are needed.

We would have to add parentheses to do that:

```
Debug.Print MsgBox(RIAJ_SCORE_RANGE(ActiveSheet.Range("E86:F91")), vbInformation)
```

And this would be illegal:

```
MsgBox (RIAJ_SCORE_RANGE(ActiveSheet.Range("E86:F91")), vbInformation)
```

...because `(RIAJ_SCORE_RANGE(ActiveSheet.Range("E86:F91")), vbInformation)` makes no sense as a value expression!

Comment: I know I'm not supposed to say thank you, but this thoughtful explanation is incredibly helpful. Thank you very much!

Comment: Looks like a useful tool. I will be using this going forward!